# Android OS killed my App(on ChromeBook) process after I change the privacy policy,

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, permission-denied, chromebook

Android OS killed my App(on ChromeBook) process after I changed the privacy policy so I know that when you change it can kill your activity, but how can I restart my activity after death?

From service I cant. ( I can see working activity with  `val runningTaskInfoList = (applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).getRunningTasks(100)` but I cant `startActivity()` from service.)

`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` doesn`t work because it is not an exception or error, the system kills the App.

I see how Adobe Acrobat work, so if you open the document and change the privacy policy in settings to denied it restarts its activity - and the logs look like this - System kill process, then the system starts a new process.

I try this, not work.

```
 fun Activity.handleUncaughtException() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
            // here you can report the throwable exception to Sentry or Crashlytics or whatever crash reporting service you're using, otherwise, you may set the throwable variable to _ if it'll remain unused
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("isCrashed", true)
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            }
            Log.DEBUG
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
           Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())
            exitProcess(2)
        }
    }


fun Activity.showUncaughtExceptionDialog() {
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra("isCrashed", false)) {
        AlertDialog.Builder(this).apply {
            setTitle("Something went wrong.")
            setMessage("Something went wrong.\nWe'll work on fixing it.")
            setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ -> }
        }.show()
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Is this a question about an android app on a chromebook (chrome-os)?

Comment: It is on chrome book, but this can be in Android mobile too. https://youtu.be/f17qe9vZ8RM?t=5